# How can I prevent the Spotlight shortcut from being re-enabled?

Tags: keyboard, spotlight

I use Raycast instead of Spotlight, so I've re-assigned the cmd-space hotkey to Raycast and disabled the shortcut in System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Spotlight.

Until recently this worked fine, but lately the shortcut keeps getting re-enabled and I have to go into System Settings and disable it after every reboot.

1. What would cause this? Searching the internet it seems like this isn't a common problem.
2. As a workaround can I write some time of a script that will run at startup to disable it?

Comment: Instead on disabling try reassigning to another key combination.

Comment: I have tried that, for some reason it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the steps from https://old.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/194xe60/spotlight_keyboard_shortcuts_reset_after_every/kjzwhif/ and tentatively I think it worked!

If it was caused by a corrupt `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` file then deleting or renaming it before disabling the shortcut should allow it to "stick".